# Getting time between two dates using DateTime

Tags: ruby, git, parsing, date, datetime

I've been tasked with writing a Ruby program to read a git log file and determine the length of a project based on the time between commits. The formatting of the date line looks like this after I finish processing everything:

`date = "Sun Jan 26 21:25:22 2014 -0600"`

I've looked through the DateTime class but can't figure out how to convert this string into an object. The closest format I can see is `httpDate` but even when I split the string into separate parts and rearranged them into the same order, I get an argument error when calling `DateTime.httpdate(date)`

How can I turn my date into a DateTime object and subtract that from another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datetime class has a parse method

[DateTime.parse](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse)

```
DateTime.parse('2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00')
                          #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>
DateTime.parse('20010203T040506+0700')
                          #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>
DateTime.parse('3rd Feb 2001 04:05:06 PM')
                          #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T16:05:06+00:00 ...>
```

DateTime.parse takes a string a returns a DateTime object.You should be able to subtract them after they are parsed.

Comment: How am I determining the oldest and most recent in order to find the time difference?

Comment: Im not sure i understand your question

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. I have many DateTimes and I needed to find the difference between the oldest and newest to get the length. I found that the normal compare operators work with DateTimes and simply looped through, replacing the most recent date when a newer was found.

Comment: Deadly nightshade: I assume you noticed that the difference between two `datetime` objects is a rational number (e.g., `19/24`), which you can of course convert to a float (`to_f`) or manipulate however you like.